# Docker unable to COPY with relative path in WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a project that has a `docker-compose.yml` set up to get it running locally for development purposes. It runs great on Linux (natively) and macOS (using Docker Desktop). I am just finishing getting it running on Windows using WSL2 and Docker Desktop 2.3.0.3 (that has proper WSL2 support). The problem is that my Dockerfile is doing a `COPY ./from /to` command and Docker doesn't seem to be able to find the file. I have set up a minimal test to recreate the problem.

I have the project set up with this directory structure:

```
docker/
    nginx/
        Dockerfile
        nginx.conf
docker-compose.yml
```

The nginx `Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.9-alpine

# Add nginx configs
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy source code for things like static assets
COPY . /application

# Expose HTTP/HTTPS ports
EXPOSE 80 443
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    nginx:
      build: docker/nginx
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      ports:
       - "80:80"
```

This is pretty basic - it's just copying the `nginx.conf` configuration file to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` inside the container.

When I run `docker-compose up` for this project, from the project root, inside WSL, I receive the following error:

```
Building nginx
Step 1/4 : FROM nginx:1.17.9-alpine
 ---> 377c0837328f
Step 2/4 : COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder502655363/docker/nginx/nginx.conf: no such file or directory
```

This is not what I expect (and not what happens on linux/mac systems) - but I assume it's messing up because of the relative path specified in the Dockerfile? Is this a Docker Desktop bug specifically with WSL, and does anybody know a workaround for the mean time? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The path in the Dockerfile should be relative to the build context path. In this example just `nginx.conf` because the context path is `docker/nginx`.